# symfony2 how to set up forms for each from displayed entities in one page?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, render

Hi i want to pass value to my controler displaying the form.
i have some page where i have displayd my apps, and for every app i have form and i want.
im using in my twig.html file this function to render form for all apps:

```
{% for application in category.applications %}
    {{ render(controller('ComzettaApplicationsBundle:Application:vote', {'inName': application})) }}
```

and my controller method begins like this:

```
/**
 * @Template
 */
public function voteAction($inName)
{
```

so does it pass the value or not ? couse it's not working :(
when i submit my form it doesnt save my entity.
but when i add a this annotation:

```
 * @Route("/rate/{inName}", name="app_rate")
```

and i run it from this rounting it works great.
why it doesnt want work when i render it ?

full template

```
{% for category in categories %}
<div id="application-list" class="row boxes">
    {% if app.request.locale == 'pl' %}
    <h1>{{ category.namePl }}</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>{{ category.nameEng }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    {% for application in category.applications %}
        {{ elementMacro.element(application.InName, csrf, csrfRate) }}
    {% else %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <p class="lead">{{ 'application.list.empty'|trans }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and here is macro:

```
{% macro element(application, csrf) %}
<div class="box col-md-4" id="{{ application }}">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><img class="icon" src="{{ path('applications_application_icon', {'name': application }) }}" alt="{{ application }}" /> {{ application }}</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pull-left">
                {{ render(controller('ApplicationsBundle:Application:vote', {'inName': application})) }}
{#                    <a href="{{ path('app_rate', {'inName': application}) }}">Link</a>#}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pull-right">{#  #}
                    <a data-toggle="modal-loading" data-target="#application-launching-modal" target="application-launcher" href="{{ path('applications_application_launch', {'name': application, '_token': csrf }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">{{ 'application.launch.button'|trans }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

next vote.html.twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Comment: Need to see the template

Comment: i edited my answer, first is the template of listAction where i display users app and want also to allow him rate every each one

Comment: You don't appear to be using the variable `inName` in either template.

Comment: couse i use it to get the aplication entity in my controler before rendering form and i get it from `application.InName`

Comment: Then you will need to look into the form itself to make sure that field is being populated.

Comment: i did it. i set up rounting for post method only and changed my vote.html.twig to this:
`<form action="{{ path('rate_app', {'inName': inName }) }}" method="post">
    {{ form_errors(form.rate) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.rate) }}
  {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>`